# glassfish standalone mode - redirecting domain.com to www.domain.com

Tags: redirect, glassfish, http-status-code-301, canonical-link

I am running Glassfish in standalone mode (without Apache) and my application is accessible on http://mydomain.com.

For SEO purposes I would like to do a 301 redirect from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com, so typing mydomain.com/page1.jsp in the browser would redirect the user to www.mydomain.com/page1.jsp

Any idea how to do it? I found this http://notsomany.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/glassfish-v2-1-1-site-redirect/ but as I understand it this redirection only works for a specific page.

Comment: In Glassfish admin (port 4848 default) you could add redirect properties under the virtual servers.... go to `localhost:4848 > Configruations > server-config > Virtual Servers > server` then add the properties.

Comment: @KevinD. What properties needs to be added?I tried "From=[Old URL] url-prefix=[New URL]" but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I could think of is using an httpd in front and working with some kind of redirection / proxy modules.
Apache mod_redirect could be a good solution here.